# Use pytorch optimizer to fit a user defined function

Tags: pytorch, minimization

I have read many tutorials on how to use PyTorch to make a regression over a data set, using, for instance, a model composed of several linear layers and the MSE loss.

Well, imagine that I know the function F depends on a variable x and some unknown parameters (p_j: j=0,..., P-1) with P relatively small, but the function is a composition of special function. So, my problem is the classical minimization knowing the data {x_i,y_i}_i<=N

```
Min_{ {p_j} } Sum_i (F(x_i;{p_j}) - y_i)^2
```

I would like to know if I can use the PyTorch optimizers and if yes how I can do it?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean you want to use a custom loss function that you know instead of MSE ?

Comment: @basilisk, well may be you are right but let me add something to be more clear. As you see in my formula you can recognize that I am using the MSE as loss, BUT the F function cannot be expressed in terms of the "usual" neural layers.  

So, imagine that I only dispose of the following function
```
C(p_0,p_1,...,p_P) = Sum_i (F(x_i;{p_j}) - y_i)^2
```
that I want to minimize. May be it is what you state that it is a custom loss.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, PyTorch experts answer that the function to minimized must be expressed in terms of torch.tensors to let the minimizers computing the gradients. So, it is not possible in my case.